# Why isn't socks5 with authentication widely supported?

Tags: socks

I've been searching around and there doesnt seem to be much socks5 support with authentication. i setup a socks5 with authentication on my ubuntu server, but doesnt seem like there are many browsers supporting it. why was socks5 even made then?

Comment: Is the question why someone created socks5?

Comment: yes.. whats the difference from socks 4 or other proxies in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**why was socks5 even made then?**

To update the SOCKS protocol to support authentication, IPv6, and UDP.